# Some Keywords of entity framework change to red color

Tags: entity-framework

I am developing a project with EF6 database first. But yesterday I changed to code first. Now everything run normally.

Except some keyword like **"Entry","Added","SaveChanges"** was marked by red color. When the mouse over these work the message occur is "cannot resolve symbol"

Code snippet:

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

NOTE: project still run successfully.

Comment: Its seem that you are trying to add new record into DB, aren't you?

Comment: @HoangNT I don't add or change database. Just convert from database first to code first

Comment: Try restart VS. Looks to be a bug with the C# parser. You can also try `Ctrl`+`A`, `Ctrl`+`X`, `Ctrl`+`V`. That will force it to reparse all your source code.

Comment: @Aron Thank you! I follow your suggestion. Restart VS, and everything normally now

Answer (score 2):

These symbols are defined in the namespace System.Data.Entity. Check if you have the proper using directive in your code file:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```